# regex in javascript to check value in range

Tags: javascript, regex

What should be the regex for checking a value is in range of (1000 to 20000)

Comment: RegEx overkill. Don't use regex for everything. GOD has given us [comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).

Comment: When asking questions show your efforts, don't expect to get code by just dumping requirements.

Comment: `var re, j, a=[]; for(j=1000;j<=20000;j++){ a.push(j);} re = new RegExp("^("+a.join("|")+")$");` (No I'm not serious. Will it work? Yes. Should you do it? No.)

Answer (score 1):

Regex is the wrong tool for this. To give you an example, let's say we want to check **values in range of 50 to 100**. With regex, you cannot think in terms of numbers, instead, you are forced to think what strings are valid representations of that range.

So, thinking in terms of strings we notice is that the first digit must be either `5`,`6`,`7`,`8` or `9` except if we are 3 digits which should be a `1`.

Let's simplify things and treat the string `100` as a special case that gives us a regexp of:

```
100|[5-9][0-9]
```

Now, let's take a look at another example. Let's say you want numbers between 1000 and 9999. We follow the above thinking which would give us:

```
[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

which can be simplified as:

```
[1-9]\d{3}
```

You can then consider the range 10000 to 20000 as a special case, write a regex for it then combine it with the above regex using the `|` operator.

I'll leave the actual solution for you to work out.

Still, regex is the wrong tool for this. It's much easier to do:

```
x >= 1000 && x <= 20000
```

And it's much easier to understand compared to the regex. Easier to understand = fewer bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Please find the code below:

```
function numInRange(numberStr) { 
  var res = numberStr.search(/(^[1-9][0-9]{3}$)|(^[1][0-9]{4}$)|(^[2][0]{4})/);
  return res == 0;
}

numInRange("999");
numInRange("1000");
numInRange("2000");
numInRange("9999");
numInRange("10000");
numInRange("20000");
numInRange("20001");
```

Answer (score 0):

^(20000|[1]{0,1}[\d]{4})$

The ^ and $ ensure that the entire input string is tested as a whole. Otherwise, we could end up with a false positive on a partial match, like 6200007 being true.

The (xxx|yyy) says "either match xxx or yyy". This was necessary because it was easy to say "match 4 number digits", basically 1000-9999. And also easy to say there either is or isn't a starting 1. But since your max was 20000, I couldn't come up with regex to say "starting 1 or 2", because a starting "2" must disallow any following digits except for 0.

So, the string must either perfectly match 20000, or any 4 numerical digits plus a possible 1 as a prefix.

To test:

`/^(20000|[1]{0,1}[\d]{4})$/.test('20000')`